# Deploying a Qt Application to an iOS device

Tags: ios, qt

On Qt Creator, when I run my application on the iOS simulator everything works fine. However, when I try and run it to the connected device, the error message below shows up:

```
[xcodebuild-release-device] Error 70
```

When I go to preferences on Qt and then Devices, it says that my device is ready to use.

How do I get my application to show up on my connected device? I would appreciate it if I could get some detailed steps on how to get this to work.

Thank you.

*The version of Qt Creator is 4.5 and Xcode is 9.2

Comment: Were there any other error messages? What version of iOS is your device running?

Comment: Check if your app settings require a newer iOS version than whats on device